# How do you convert A binary number to a BigInteger in Java?

Tags: java, binary, biginteger

I needed to convert a very big binary value into its decimal equivalent. As it is a big integer I was using BigInteger. So how do I convert this binary number to a BigInteger?

Comment: How do we have this binary number? As a byte array?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have the `String` representation of your binary number, provide it to this overloaded `BigInteger` constructor to create an instance:

```
BigInteger(String val, int radix);
```

In your case, radix is clearly 2, i.e. you can use something like this:

```
BigInteger yourNumber = new BigInteger("101000101110...1010", 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have binary String you can convert it to `BigInteger` like this:

```
 String binaryString = "1010110101011010101010101101010101100101011010001010001100101110";
 BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(binaryString, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    String binaryValue = "11111111";
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(binaryValue, 2);
```